# How I can add a self argument here?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is a function for a discord bot, it counts bad words in the `BadWords` variable, but the console shows me "TypeError: on_message() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given". Here is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(self):
    BadWords = ["*Bad words string*"]

    if message.content == BadWords:
        await ctx.send("Uh Oh, wacth your vocabulary")
```

Comment: Is this a member function of a class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the word 'self'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self)

Answer (score 3):

You should add an argument to your method:

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
```

Comment: If you want to use self, than on_message should be a method of a class^

Comment: To add onto the answer, the bad words aren't being counted in `BadWords`, and the code probably isn't going to function as intended as is when comparing the entirety of the message content to a list. OP should also consider that when adding an argument as @Andrey suggested.